# UITypeEditor no guarda cambios en el diseñador de VS

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy trabajando en un control que posee una propiedad personalizada en Winform, el problema es que al tratar de modificar la propiedad a través de un "Editor Modal", se modifican los cambios en tiempo de diseño actual pero al cerrar y abrir la previsualización del formulario los cambios no permanecen y la clase "Form1.Designer.cs" no sufre ningún cambio.

He investigado mucho sobre el tema incluso cambiar la versión del proyecto "1.0.0.0" por "1.0.0.*" o implementar la interfaz INotifyPropertyChanged pero no funciona, no encuentro la solución este es el código:

**Control:**

```
public class CustomButton : UserControl
{
    public CustomButton(){}

    private FontReader _fontreader;

    [Category(""), Description("")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public FontReader FontReader
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fontreader == null)
                _fontreader = new FontReader();

            return _fontreader;
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase:**

```
[Editor(typeof(FontreaderEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class FontReader : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    internal FontReader()
    {
        _foreColor = Color.DimGray;
        _familyName = "Tahoma";
    }

    Color _foreColor;
    string _familyName;
    bool _isDisposed;

    [Category(""), Description("")]
    public Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return _foreColor; }
        set
        {
            _foreColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ForeColor");
        }
    }

    [Category(""), Description("")]
    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return _familyName; }
        set
        {
            _familyName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FamilyName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        //Invoca el evento que contendra el nombre del control
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

**UITypeEditor:**

```
internal class FontreaderEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        else
            return base.GetEditStyle(context);
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService service = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
        FontReader fontreader = (FontReader)value;

        if (fontreader == null)
            fontreader = new FontReader();

        if (service != null)
        {
            using (ReaderEditor frmReaderEditor = new ReaderEditor(fontreader))
            {
                 //Formulario modal
                if (service.ShowDialog(frmReaderEditor) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    value = frmReaderEditor.FontReader;
                }

                return value;
            }
        }

        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }

}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**
Este es el formulario que he utilizado para actualizar las propiedades de mi clase:

```
public partial class ReaderEditor : Form
{
    public ReaderEditor(FontReader fontreader)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FontReader = fontreader;
        txtFamilyName.Text = FontReader.FamilyName;
        btnForeColor.BackColor = FontReader.ForeColor;
    }

    public FontReader FontReader
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontReader.FamilyName = txtFamilyName.Text;
        FontReader.ForeColor = btnForeColor.BackColor;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.Color = btnForeColor.BackColor;

        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            btnForeColor.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
    }
}
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda!.

Comment: Podrías agregar la clase `ReaderEditor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba tratando de hacer que la actualización de las propiedades sea independiente y no a nivel de la propiedad principal.

**FontReader**

```
[Editor(typeof(FontReaderEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class FontReader
{
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "DimGray")]
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("Tahoma")]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}
```

**FontReaderEditor**

```
internal class FontReaderEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if (provider == null) return value;

        var svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
        var fontReader = value as FontReader;

        if (svc == null || fontReader == null) return fontReader;

        using (var form = new ReaderEditor(fontReader))
        {
            if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return new FontReader
                {
                    ForeColor = form.Fontreader.ForeColor,
                    FamilyName = form.Fontreader.FamilyName
                };
            }
        }

        return fontReader;
    }
}
```

**UserControl1**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    FontReader _fontreader;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _fontreader = new FontReader();
    }

    [Category("ACATEGORIA"), Description("DESCRIPCION")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public FontReader FontReader
    {
        get
        {
            return _fontreader;
        }

        set
        {
            _fontreader = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FontReader));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Prueba**

[image: Prueba de actualización de propiedades]

> Voy a seguir revisando para hacer que la actualización sea independiente

Comment: Excelente!!! Muchas Gracias!! uno de los problemas que había tenido era que el diseñador de VS generaba la instancia de la clase de esta manera micontrol.FonReader = new FontReader(); y luego asignaba el valor a las propiedades, es por ello que colocaba la propiedad solo de lectura "get", muchas gracias de nuevo esto es exactamente lo que necesitaba!